# ESP32 Telegram Stops sending messages after the first

Tags: telegram-bot, esp32

Here's a simple ESP32 program to test UniversalTelegrambBot.  It connects to wifi without a problem (using external confidential file).  It sends a startup message from Setup but never sends the dummy string data from the loop.  The loop is running and printing out the value that should be sent but bot.sendMessage returns false every loop cycle.  If I comment out the startup message then the loop sends the first value and no thereafter.
Using Arduino v 1.8.1, UniversalTelegrambot v 1.3.0, ArduinoJson v 6.19.4 with Adafruit Huzzah ESP32.

```
     /****************************************************************
     * 
     * Sends dummy temperature value string to Telegram account 
     * once ever N minutes
     * 
     * 
     * HARDWARE:
     * Adafruit Huzzah ESP32
     * 
     * SOFTWARE:
     * Arduino v 1.8.19
     * UniversalTelegramBot v 1.3.0
     * ArduinoJson v 6.19.
     * 
     * THIS CODE ONLY SENDS THE FIRST VALUE THEN FAILS TO SEND THE REST
     * WHY?
     * 
     * To program ESP32:
          Hold GPIO0 button down
          Press/release Reset button
          Release GPIO0 button
          When programming finishes, toggle reset button
    
    *****************************************************************/
    
    #include <WiFi.h>
    #include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
    #include <WiFiMulti.h>
    #include <UniversalTelegramBot.h>
    #include <ArduinoJson.h>
    #include "Credentials.h"
    
    WiFiMulti wifiMulti;
    
    #define VER "TelegramBotDemo_v2"
    
    // Turn on debugging
    #define MY_DEBUG
    
    // ************** Print to serial only when MY_DEBUG is defined *****************
    #ifdef MY_DEBUG
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(x)     Serial.print (x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTLNF(x)   Serial.println (x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINT(x)      Serial.print (x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTDEC(x)   Serial.print (x, DEC)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTLN(x)    Serial.println (x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTHEX(x)   Serial.print(x,HEX)
    #else
    #define DEBUG_PRINTF(x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTLNF(x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINT(x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTDEC(x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTLN(x)
    #define DEBUG_PRINTHEX(x)
    #endif
    
    bool wifiFound = false;
    
    // Set GPIOs for LED and IO_PIN
    const int BUILTIN_LED_PIN = 13; //optional
    const int IO_PIN = 0;
    float temp = 49.9;
    bool state;
    String TempState = "NONE";
    bool firstTime = true;
    unsigned long previousMillis = 0; 
    const long TIMER_INTERVAL = 1; // mins (set to 1 for test otherwise 60)
    #define LED_ON HIGH
    #define LED_OFF LOW
    
    WiFiClientSecure secured_client;
    UniversalTelegramBot bot(BOTtoken, secured_client);
    
    
    /**********************************************
      Round float to places places, return as string
    ***********************************************/
    String rndS(float value, byte places)
    {
      //Storage for displaying float converted to char array
      char valueChar[10];
      dtostrf(value, 5, places, valueChar); //convert float to char array
      String s = (String)valueChar;
      s.trim();  //remove whitespace
      return s ;
    }
    
    /************************************
     * Connect to wifi and display stats
     ************************************/
    boolean wifiConnect()
    {
      DEBUG_PRINTLN();
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
    
      uint32_t looptime = millis();
      uint8_t loopCount = 0;
      
      while (wifiMulti.run() != WL_CONNECTED)
      {
        while (millis() - looptime < 500L) yield(); // use this and not delay()
        looptime = millis();
        DEBUG_PRINT(".");
        if(++loopCount >= 20){
          DEBUG_PRINTLN("Timed out waiting for wiFi");
          return false;
        }
      }
    
      DEBUG_PRINTLN("");
    //  DEBUG_PRINT(F("SSID:"));
    //  DEBUG_PRINTLN(WiFi.SSID());
    //  DEBUG_PRINT(F("MAC:"));
    //  DEBUG_PRINTLN(WiFi.macAddress());
      DEBUG_PRINT(F("IP address:"));
      DEBUG_PRINTLN(WiFi.localIP());
      DEBUG_PRINT(F("RSSI:"));
      DEBUG_PRINTLN(WiFi.RSSI());
      DEBUG_PRINTLN("WiFi Connected");
      DEBUG_PRINTLN("");
      
      return true;
    }
    
    
    
    /****************** SETUP ***************************/
    void setup() {
      // Serial port for debugging purposes
      Serial.begin(115200);  
      Serial.println(VER);
      
      // Set RED LED off (LOW)
      pinMode(BUILTIN_LED_PIN, OUTPUT);
      digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED_PIN, LED_OFF);
      
      secured_client.setCACert(TELEGRAM_CERTIFICATE_ROOT); // Add root certificate for api.telegram.org
    
      // Connect to Wi-Fi
      WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
      // add multiple WAPs; it will pick the strongest
      wifiMulti.addAP(ssid1, pass1);
      wifiMulti.addAP(ssid2, pass2);
      wifiMulti.addAP(ssid3, pass3);
    
      if(wifiConnect()){
        delay(500);
        wifiFound = true;  // not used
      }
      else
        exit(0);
        
      WiFi.setSleep(false);
    
      // Send startup message (this always works)
      if(bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "Bot started up", ""))
        DEBUG_PRINTLN("Startup Message sent");
      else 
        DEBUG_PRINTLN("Startup Message NOT sent");
      
      unsigned long previousMillis = millis();
    }  // END OF SETUP
    
    
    /****************** LOOP ***************************/
    void loop() {    
      if(millis() - previousMillis >= TIMER_INTERVAL*60000UL || firstTime) {
        previousMillis = millis();
        firstTime = false;
         
        digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED_PIN, LED_ON); // Flash RED LED
        delay(200);
        digitalWrite(BUILTIN_LED_PIN,LED_OFF);
    
        TempState = String(rndS(temp,1));
        DEBUG_PRINTLN(TempState);
     
        if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
          
          //Send dummy string value ( this never works unless I comment out
          // the startup message, then it works only once )
          if(bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "Temp: " + TempState, ""))
            DEBUG_PRINTLN("Message sent");
          else 
            DEBUG_PRINTLN("Message NOT sent");
        }
        else
          DEBUG_PRINTLN("WiFi NOT connected");
      
      } // END interval timer
    
    } // END LOOP
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't know what else to say.  The program runs but only sends one value to my Telegram account.  It is supposed to send a value every minute.

Comment: bot.sendMessage(CHAT_ID, "STRING", "") returns true the first time it's encountered ( in Setup() ) and I get a message in my account but then returns false from then on ( in loop() ) and no messages are received.  If I comment out the sendMessage in Setup() then the sendMessage in the loop() sends the first time through and then never again.  I can see all this happening in the Serial Monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.  I dumped UTB and went with CTBot 2.1.9 and it works fine.